# 'Tile Right' keyboard shortcut stopped working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm facing a weird problem: after a few hours of usage, the 'Tile Right' keyboard shortcut has stopped working. I can still tile a window to the left with the shortcut just fine, but not to the right.

I have restarted the laptop several times meanwhile and have re-assigned the shortcut to other keys, but to no avail.

Has anyone faced this before? I'm not sure how to further debug this.

I'm running a pretty much stock 5.1. I've only installed VSCode and backport-iwlwifi-dkms (I need kernel 5.4, otherwise I need to add this to have wifi) from other PPAs.

Thanks!

Comment: `ctrl + windows + right arrow` works flawlessly | I never faced the tile bug you're talking about. Elementary 5.1 Hera (kernel 5.4)